# Bookshelf.js where with json column Postgresql

Tags: json, postgresql, bookshelf.js

I have a problem with Bookshelf, I want use query to columns json type
My table have columns 'data' type json, I want get all element with in this columns 'team' = 'PSG'

I test:

```
  collection.query('whereRaw', "data->'team'->>'PSG'");
```

I have this error

> "argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type text"

Or I test

```
collection.query('where', "data", "#>", "'{team, PSG}'");
```

I have this error

> "The operator \"#>\" is not permitted"

I think that have a report with https://github.com/tgriesser/bookshelf/issues/550

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer:**

```
collection.query('where', 'data', '@>', '{"team": "PSG"}');
```

**Explanation:**

Say you have a table `foos`, where an element `foo` is

```
 ------------------------
| id | attr              |
 ------------------------
| 0  |{ "bar": "fooBar"} | 
 ------------------------
| 1  |{ "bar": "fooFoo"} | 
 ------------------------
```

The raw query for that would be like.

```
select * from "foos" where "attr" @> '{"bar":"fooBar"}';
```

Now in Bookshelf if you have a model Foo that represent table foos it the query should be like.

```
Foo.where('attr', '@>', '{"bar":"fooBar"}').fetch().then(function(rows){});
```

Now for your case it should be like

```
collection.query('where', 'data', '@>', '{"team": "PSG"}');
```

Hopefully *Zlatan Approves* it.

Comment: I'm using the same query, but still getting error,  `Unhandled rejection error: select "foo".* from "foo" where "attr" @> $1 limit $2 - operator does not exist: json @> unknown`.

Comment: Can you please run your knex query with debug flag and post your exact query?

Comment: Whoever is trying to accomplish this same task, do not follow these instructions.  Vasanth's comment from Oct 19 '16 still hold true.  PostgreSQL generates the following error: ERROR:  operator does not exist: json @> unknown
LINE 1: ...t * from "users" where "email_subscription_prefs" @> '{"mark...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.